# Ad style sheet bleeding into main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising, design

Exhibit A:

[image: screenshot]

Normally the “Add Comment” button is dark grey, not orange. The orange button only seems to appear with the particular advertisement next to it. Reloading the page with a different advertisement fixes the problem. But when this particular ad resurfaces, the button is once again orange.

FWIW I actually prefer the orange button.

Comment: The "Post your answer" button gets the same treatment with the same add.

Comment: Heh, I thought that was [meta-tag:status-by-design]! Prefer the orange button as well...

Comment: [hmm](http://i.imgur.com/GAAOIN9.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My fault. Careers leaked a little CSS onto the page with that ad. This is fixed now.

[image: F1x3d]